# uwsgi/nginx, how does permissions works? what is the difference between uid/gid and chown-socket?

Tags: nginx, virtualenv, uwsgi

I have multiple sites, each site has his own uwsgi config file that looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
...
uid = nginx
gid = mysite
chown-socket = nginx:mysite
...
```

So my socket is under /var/sockets/:

```
srwxr-xr-x 1 nginx mysite 0 Sep 13 20:12 mysite_uwsgi.sock
```

My application path is **/srv/www/mysite/**, which is under nginx:mysite as well, otherwise nginx service will not be able to access to folders when I want to upload files. (all folder under 755, files 644)

Normally, folder are **drwxr-xr-x 6 nginx mysite** and files **-rw-r--r-- 1 nginx mysite**. And when I upload a file, it uploads as **-rw------- 1 nginx mysite**. Is this right? why it doesn't upload as 0644 as well? What determines under who is the owner/group and permissions that this file should have?

My virtualenv (venv folder) is under **nginx:mysite** (all folder under 755, files 644) as well. Is this going to giving me problems in a future? What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The nginx doesn't attribute permissions to folders, the operative system, in case linux does the job. Nginx only creates one user normally www-data witch the wsgi interpreter you are using is going to use, for example gunicorn or fastcgi. 
The folder you want to be the destination of the upload of files, you are giving more permission to the folder than to the files, the permissions of folder are different than the permissions of the files.

Think this way, the permissions 764 for example is decimal but what 764 means ? We separate the three digits 7-6-4 and he convert each digit to binary witch gives us 111-110-100, in all permissions they are for read, write and execute. So you are giving :

First digit 111 - rwe, permittion to the user read read the file,write the file and execute
Second digit 110 - rw, permittion to the users of the group to read and write
Third digit 100 - The others users to read the file and not to write or execute.

This apply's to the files and directory's, you can change the attributes with chmod.